# How to execute a shell command before the ENTRYPOINT via the dockerfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, environment-variables

I have the following file for my nodejs project

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install



# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Replace with env variable
RUN envsubs < fil1 > file2

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I run the docker container with the -e flag providing the environment variable

But I do not see the replacement. Will the Run ccommand be excuted when the env variable is available?

Comment: Side note: as you set the workdir, next commands will be relative to this path, so you can change `COPY package.json /usr/src/app/` to `COPY package.json package.json`, and `COPY . /usr/src/app` to `COPY . .`

Comment: Moreover, no need to `RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app` as WORKDIR will create it if it doesn't exists. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir

Comment: What is `envsubs < fil1 > file2` ?

Comment: the command that replaces the variable in file 1 and file 2 is the output file

Answer (score 115, accepted):

### Images are immutable

Dockerfile defines the build process for an image. Once built, the image is immutable (cannot be changed). Runtime variables are not something that would be baked into this immutable image. So Dockerfile is the wrong place to address this.

### Using an entrypoint script

What you probably want to to do is override the default `ENTRYPOINT` with your own script, and have that script do something with environment variables. Since the entrypoint script would execute at runtime (when the container starts), this is the correct time to gather environment variables and do something with them.

First, you need to adjust your Dockerfile to know about an entrypoint script. While Dockerfile is not directly involved in handling the environment variable, it still needs to know about this script, because the script will be baked into your image.

**Dockerfile:**

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Now, write an entrypoint script which does whatever setup is needed *before* the command is run, and at the end, `exec` the command itself.

**entrypoint.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Where $ENVSUBS is whatever command you are looking to run
$ENVSUBS < file1 > file2

npm install

# This will exec the CMD from your Dockerfile, i.e. "npm start"
exec "$@"
```

Here, I have included `npm install`, since you asked about this in the comments. I will note that this will run `npm install` *on every run*. If that's appropriate, fine, but I wanted to point out it will run every time, which will add some latency to your startup time.

Now rebuild your image, so the entrypoint script is a part of it.

### Using environment variables at runtime

The entrypoint script knows how to use the environment variable, but you still have to tell Docker to import the variable at runtime. You can use the `-e` flag to `docker run` to do so.

```
docker run -e "ENVSUBS=$ENVSUBS" <image_name>
```

Here, Docker is told to define an environment variable `ENVSUBS`, and the value it is assigned is the value of `$ENVSUBS` from the current shell environment.

### How entrypoint scripts work

I'll elaborate a bit on this, because in the comments, it seemed you were a little foggy on how this fits together.

When Docker starts a container, it executes one (and only one) command inside the container. This command becomes PID 1, just like `init` or `systemd` on a typical Linux system. This process is responsible for running any other processes the container needs to have.

By default, the `ENTRYPOINT` is `/bin/sh -c`. You can override it in Dockerfile, or docker-compose.yml, or using the docker command.

When a container is started, Docker runs the entrypoint command, and passes the command (`CMD`) to it as an argument list. Earlier, we defined our own `ENTRYPOINT` as `/entrypoint.sh`. That means that in your case, this is what Docker will execute in the container when it starts:

```
/entrypoint.sh npm start
```

Because `["npm", "start"]` was defined as the command, that is what gets passed as an argument list to the entrypoint script.

Because we defined an environment variable using the `-e` flag, this entrypoint script (and its children) will have access to that environment variable.

At the end of the entrypoint script, we run `exec "$@"`. Because `$@` expands to the argument list passed to the script, this will run

```
exec npm start
```

And because `exec` runs its arguments as a command, *replacing* the current process with itself, when you are done, `npm start` becomes PID 1 in your container.

### Why you can't use multiple CMDs

In the comments, you asked whether you can define multiple `CMD` entries to run multiple things.

You can only have one `ENTRYPOINT` and one `CMD` defined. These are not used at all during the build process. Unlike `RUN` and `COPY`, they are not executed during the build. They are added as metadata items to the image once it is built.

It is only later, when the image is run as a container, that these metadata fields are read, and used to start the container.

As mentioned earlier, the entrypoint is what is really run, and it is passed the `CMD` as an argument list. The reason they are separate is partly historical. In early versions of Docker, `CMD` was the only available option, and `ENTRYPOINT` was fixed as being `/bin/sh -c`. But due to situations like this one, Docker eventually allowed `ENTRYPOINT` to be defined by the user.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, if multiple commands are needed at start up the should be added as scripts

Comment: @user_mda A container can only run _one_ command. Just like a Linux system runs one command (`init` or `systemd`) and it is then responsible for starting up everything else. Since you can only run one thing (an entrypoint), if you want to do more things than that, you have to use a script like this to do some things before forking off the actual command you wanted to run (in this case, `npm start`).

Comment: @user_mda By default, the `ENTRYPOINT` is `/bin/sh -c`, and your `CMD` is passed to that as an argument. All we're doing here is using a script instead of `/bin/sh -c`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, tryng out now.. On a side note, does multiple CMD instructions serve the purpose?

Comment: @user_mda No, you can only have one `CMD` and one `ENTRYPOINT` maximum per image.

Comment: OK - I want to buiild and run the project after the excution of script So after the ntrypoint I want to say npm install and then npm start

Comment: @user_mda I have rewritten my answer to be a bit more clear, and I included `npm install` as well.

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly. Also thanks a lot for the details , very helpful!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. This is a fantastic write-up. Thank you for explaining this so clearly!

Answer (score 5):

For images with `bash` as the default entrypoint, this is what I do to allow myself to run some scripts before shell start if needed:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY init.sh /root/init.sh
RUN echo 'a=(${BEFORE_SHELL//:/ }); for c in ${a[@]}; do source $x; done' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and if you want to source a script at container login you pass its path in the environment variable `BEFORE_SHELL`. Example using docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  shell:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      BEFORE_SHELL: '/root/init.sh'
```

Some remarks:

- If `BEFORE_SHELL` is not set then nothing happens (we have the default behavior)
- You can pass any script path available in the container, included mounted ones
- The scripts are sourced so variables defined in the scripts will be available in the container
- Multiple scripts can be passed (use a `:` to separate the paths)

Comment: Thanks for the strategy.  Really love the idea of setting a $BEFORE_SHELL env variable.  Was expecting something like this to be built in by default, but since it's not, love the idea of building it easily.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the Run ccommand be excuted when the env variable is available?

Environnement variables set with `-e` flag are set when you `run` the container.

Problem is, Dockerfile is read on container `build`, so the `RUN` command will **not** be aware of thoses environnement variables.

The way to have environment variables set on build, is to add in your Dockerfile, `ENV` line. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/environment-replacement)

So your Dockerfile may be :

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /src
ADD package.json .

ENV A YOLO

RUN echo "$A"
```

And the output :

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 1 : FROM node:latest
 ---> f5eca816b45d
Step 2 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ede3b23756d
Step 3 : ADD package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a4671a30bfe4
Step 4 : ENV A YOLO
 ---> Running in 7c325474af3c
 ---> eeefe2c8bc47
Removing intermediate container 7c325474af3c
Step 5 : RUN echo "$A"
 ---> Running in 35e0d85d8ce2
YOLO
 ---> 78d5df7d2322
```

You see at the before-last line when the `RUN` command launched, the container is aware the envrionment variable is set.

Comment: So, I dont know the value of the environment variable, it is set by another process when the container is launched. I just want to read it and overwrite a file, any way to achive this?

Comment: what is the correct way to first read the env variable after container runs and then run the entrypoint command?

Answer (score 0):

I had an [extremely stubborn container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) that would not run anything on startup. This technique workd well, and took me a day to find as every single other possible technique failed.

- Run `docker inspect postgres` to find entrypoint script. In this case, it was `docker-entrypoint.sh`. This might vary by container type and Docker version.
- Open a shell into the container, then find the full path: `find / -name docker-entrypoint.sh`
- Inspect the file: `cat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`

In the Dockerfile, use SED to insert line 2 (using `2i`).

```
# Insert into Dockerfile 
RUN sed -i '2iecho Run on startup as user `whoami`.' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

In my particular case, Docker ran this script twice on startup: first as root, then as user `postgres`. Can use the `test` to only run the command under root.