# How to setup Docker Compose without a Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, rethinkdb

I have spend the last few hours trying to setup 2 default images of nodejs 14 and rethinkdb 2.3.5, so sorry if the tone is a little frustrated but I am currently frustrated.

My requirements are seemingly super simple.

#### I want to:

1. download the default images for nodejs 14 and rethinkdb 2.3.5
2. copy everything from my current directory into the nodejs 14 image.
3. I want the nodejs image to depend on the RethinkDB image.
4. run 2 commands in the nodejs 14 image; `npm ci` and `npm test`.
5. see the stdout from the tests.

#### I do not need:

1. any ports to be accessible to the host machine.
2. to customize any Dockerfile or make any changes to the default images.
3. any updates from the host machine file-system to the containers.
4. to copy any data from the host machine to the RethinkDB container.

#### Why?

I want the tests to be reproducible across all developer machines - currently no CI. Regardless of where the developer has the project on their hard drive.

I have a single `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  tests:
    image: node:14
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # command:
    #  - npm ci
    #  - npm test
    volumes:
      - ".:/cli-app"
    depends_on:
      - rethinkdb

  rethinkdb:
    image: rethinkdb
    ports:
      - "28015:28015"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./data: /data"
    command: rethinkdb --bindall --data /data
```

Answer (score 27):

> The point of this answer is **not** to give the must succinct explanation (briefly and clearly expressed) as possible but to highlight all the confusion that the current documentation at docs.docker.com and hub.docker.com create. Eventually I/we will get it right and a succinct answer can be written.

The corrected `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  tests:
    image: "node:14"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    container_name: nodejs
    depends_on:
      - rethinkdb
    command: bash -c "npm ci && npm test"

  rethinkdb:
    image: rethinkdb:2.3.5
    container_name: rethinkdb
```

### The frustrating part!

Right off the bat, the documentation at docs.docker.com and hub.docker.com is arguably the worse documentation ever written, since it is a) **wrong**, b) **assumes prior knowledge**.

*If any of the following is wrong - blame the horrible documentation.*

[image]

**No, you do not need a *Dockerfile* unless you plan to built your own image.**

So after wasting an hour or so on different [outdated](https://gist.github.com/dalanmiller/d925a6b5311bdbeff5fafa1ba4a08652) [examples](https://github.com/grzesiek/docker-rethinkdb/blob/master/Dockerfile), you might be lucky to discover that everything you have tried with `context` to get around the absolute path examples... **does not matter at all** unless you are creating your own image from scratch (which 90% of docker users, do not need).

> **Tip** use `docker system prune` to delete all those unfortunate useless docker containers you've creating by following example.

Next up, find the correct docker containers.

Presenting: [nodejs](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) official docker image!
[image]
[image]

## Did you see the image name that we need?

[image]

**Not one place does it say `image`. You just have to know.**

#### Line by line explanation to `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"
```

Uses version 3.x of the syntax. The syntax varies from Docker engine versions as listed at [Compose and Docker compatibility matrix](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix).

```yaml
services:
```

Each container image is a service in Docker Compose terminology. `tests` and `rethinkdb` are my names for 2 images. You can name them as you want but we will use this name later to create a dependency between the 2 images (one needs to be online before the other).

```yaml
services:
  tests:
    ...
  rethinkdb:
    ...
```

`tests` and `rethinkdb` are the two services that we will get Docker Compose to run for us.

### Fix: 1. download the default images for nodejs 14 and rethinkdb 2.3.5

```yaml
    image: "node:14"
```

Luckily the nodejs Docker developers included extremely nice documentation in lieu of proper standard documentation at [hub.docker.com/_/node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node).

> Image variants: The defacto image **[`node:<version>`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#nodeversion)** and [`node:<version>-alpine`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#nodealpine) `node:<version>-alpine` image is based on the popular Alpine Linux project, which is much smaller than most distribution base images (~5MB), and thus leads to much slimmer images in general..

```yaml
    image: rethinkdb:2.3.5
```

Unfortunately, the less funded RethinkDB project, [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb) <del>does not have such information.</del> Actually if you scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page, you will find **Image Variants** (sorry, I can not link to headings on hub.docker.com since they do not have an `id` or `name` attribute). The 2 versions you will want to use is either `rethinkdb:<version>` or `rethinkdb:<version>-slim`.

Q:
So what about the much more dominant **Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links** section?

A:
They are less frequently needed and are specialized docker images. In the RethinkDB case, it is the RethinkDB database install on Debian Buster and CentOS. There is also a link to some versions but not all. So it's a selected list of images, you probably do not want. Remember you have to click on *Tags* or the small grey link; *View Available Tags* (see the image above with the red squares - sorry no anchor linking support on SO either).

### Fix: 2. copy everything from my current directory into the nodejs 14 image.

```yaml
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
```

If you look up `user` or `working_dir` on [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir), you are out of luck without prior knowledge with `docker`. It only states that:

> Each of these is a single value, analogous to its docker run counterpart. Note that mac_address is a legacy option.

The goal here is to copy the current directory (where `docker-compose.yml` is located) to the `tests` service which pulls the `node:14` image. We need to create a directory in our container where our current directory on our machine will be copied to. Later on, we want to execute some commands in that directory and we do not want to run stuff as `sudo`, so the natural placement is in our user home directory (`~/`).

We need:

1. A user in our `nodejs` container.
2. Create a directory in the user home directory in our `nodejs` container.
3. Map our current directory on our machine to the new directory in our `nodejs` container.

After reading [How to use this image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image) that the nodejs developers wrote, we can see in the example that there is a `node` user in the image.
The example also shows which Docker Compose configurations we need.

```yaml
    user: "node"
```

Presumably use the *node*  user defined in `image: "node:14"`.

```yaml
    working_dir: /home/node/app
```

Create an *app* directory inside the `node` user's *home* directory.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
```

Map our current directory on our machine to the */home/node/app* directory inside the `tests` container (which uses `image: "node:14"`).

### Fix: 3. I want the nodejs image to depend on the RethinkDB image.

```yaml
    container_name: nodejs
```

Turns out that defining `container_name` is purely cosmetic. It does not help you to link network or start one container before the other. It is just a name. While your containers are running you can use `docker ps` to see them or `docker ps -a` to see all containers, even shut downed ones. In the *NAMES* column the `container_name` is written. If you do not define `container_name`, then they will be called your directory name and the service name, post-fixed with a incremental number.

`docker ps` with `container_name` while running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               PORTS                            NAMES
5272576f8555        node:14                                              nodejs
fb11d5ce049b        rethinkdb:2.3.5     8080/tcp, 28015/tcp, 29015/tcp   rethinkdb
```

`docker ps` **without** `container_name` while running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               PORTS                            NAMES
528e5ee37956        node:14                                              data_access_layer_tests_1
e80682b806fc        rethinkdb:2.3.5     8080/tcp, 28015/tcp, 29015/tcp   data_access_layer_rethinkdb_1
```

```yaml
    depends_on:
      - rethinkdb
```

`depends_on` is the magic one! It tells Docker Compose that the `rethinkdb` container must be <del>online</del> started before *this* container.

This in a rare case of the [Docker Compose documentation (`depends_on`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) actually being good.

Unfortunately `depends_on` does not guarantee that the depending image is online, as you would expect, but the documentation is also very clear in this case and offer another solution. In our case, it does not matter much since the `rethinkdb` container starts fast enough (`npm ci` in `nodejs` will take way longer than the startup time of `rethinkdb`).

### Fix: 4. run 2 commands in the nodejs 14 image; npm ci and npm test.

```yaml
    command: "npm ci && npm test"
```

Now we can run some commands inside our docker container, <del>as if we where running them on our machine in our project directory.</del> **Of course not.** The above will only execute `npm ci`. See the SO answer [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064175/205696). Docker uses an obscure difficult to fathom variant of shell script that can execute one, and only one command, with parameters. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) says it is similar to [the docker `CMD` key](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) but neither sites explain why some POSIX shell commands work and others don't but we assume that it made life easier for Docker developers :)

The correct way to execute multiple commands, is:

```yaml
    command: bash -c "npm ci && npm test"
```

Please see ["Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064175/205696).

`npm ci` installs all npm packages from *package-lock.json* and `npm test` runs our `"test"` script in *package.json*.

You might think that you can write multiple commands in an YAML array but doing so will, in this case apparently, tell node to `require` them as modules inside the container and you will get errors like:

```
nodejs       | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
nodejs       |   throw err;
nodejs       |   ^
nodejs       |
nodejs       | Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/app/npm ci'
nodejs       |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
nodejs       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
nodejs       |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
nodejs       |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
nodejs       |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
nodejs       |   requireStack: []
nodejs       | }
```

```yaml
    command:
      - "npm ci"
      - "npm test"
```

The above will **not** work!

<del>Instead use the usual [`&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command) to execute a series of successful commands.</del> Again, [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064175/205696) is the correct documentation.

Actually, forget the above and use [`entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#entrypoint) to point to a bash file where you write all of your commands.

### Fix: 5. see the stdout from the tests.

**DO NOT USE `docker-compose up -d`!**

You do not have to do anything here. Even though every Docker Compose tutorial will tell you to run in detached mode. You will not see stdout or stderr. Just loose the `-d`.

`docker-compose up` is the way to go!

If you really have to run in detached mode, you can see the output via `docker logs [container id]` and get the container id via `docker ps` or `docker ps -a`. The latter is used if your containers are not currently running.

### `docker-compose.yml` keys that look like they are needed

<del>Turns out that Docker comes with a lot of sane defaults which you should not mess with unless you really have to.</del>

```yaml
    ports:
      - "28015:28015"
      - "8080:8080"
```

You do not need to expose ports in a `docker-compose.yml` unless you need to expose the ports to your local machine or outside network, even though every example out there does it. For example, if you need access to `localhost:8080` (in RethinkDB that is the dashboard), then you have to add:

```yaml
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

Your other services/containers will have access to both port `28015` and `8080`, using the service name as hostname, without you have to specify anything in your `docker-compose.yml`. E.g. in this case `rethinkdb:28015`. See below for more information.

<del>You do not need to expose ports in a `docker-compose.yml` even though every example out there does it. Chances are that the image you use, already exposes the default ports used by the containerized software you need. The above example is the default ports that RethinkDB uses and they are exposed without you having to write them.</del>

---

```yaml
    links:
      - rethinkdb
```

`links` seems like a way to connect two distinct containers but it turns out that all containers share network, so you do not have to. The [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links) comes with a big red WARNING, which suggest that you use [user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). Which in turn says that:

> By default Compose sets up a single [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

<del>That's a convoluted way of saying that inside your Docker Compose containers, you can connect to ports and IP address just as you would, had it been on your local machine.</del>

<del>So if container A's image exposes `172.18.0.2:28015` then you can connect from container B using that exact address. E.i. IP: `172.18.0.2` and port: `28015`.</del> Scratch that! The exposed IP addresses are **not** stable. Docker will change them, for various (unknown) reasons.

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

**Means that your service name is used as hostname, in the same way you would define it in your */etc/hosts* file.** Or similar to how DNS links stackoverflow.com to 151.101.193.69.

So if container `rethinkdb` exposes port `28015` then it will be accessible from the `nodejs` container via `rethinkdb:28015`.

**BEWARE** that the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) says:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

> Each container can now look up the hostname `web` or `db` and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, `web`’s application code could connect to the URL `postgres://db:5432` and start using the Postgres database.

<del>In the [example for Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) `postgres` is the `image`, `db` is the service name and `5432` is the port number. This is does **not** work in my experience. You need to use the service name and **never** the `image` name. So the correct way to connect from `web` to `db` is to use the URL **`db:5232`**.</del> @jonrsharpe points out that the protocol (`postgres://`) just happens to match the image name.

*The following is a *correction* of my previous understanding of the example.*

In the [example for Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) `postgres` is the protocol (similar to `https`), `db` is the service name and `5432` is the port number. You need to use the service name, to get the correct IP address. So the correct way to connect from `web` to `db` is to use the URL **`[protocol]://db:5232`**. Where `protocol` can be `http`, `https`, `progres`, etc.

Since all containers are within the same network, you **do not need** the `ports` key unless you need to expose a service to your local machine (or outside network).

---

```yaml
    volumes:
      - "./data: /data"
```

Every RethinkDB `Dockerfile` has this but this is only needed if you want to copy files from your local machine into the container. In this case we do not want to preload the database with anything, so we do not have any files to seed the database with, hence the `volumes` key is not needed.

Comment: If I get a sudden surge of energy, I will write another answer with the same information but without the frustrations... Will probably be one third length of this.

Comment: Bonus info: use [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) to get docker to automatically load environment variables. These will take precedence over your `.env` file by [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), so you do not need to swap `.env` file for testing. Much simpler than doing that from a script via [`entrypoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518225/205696)!

Comment: This isn't even *right*, for example in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65619963/14 `db:5432` (`<service>:<port>`) *is* what those docs say to use, you've apparently been confused by the fact that the *protocol* (`postgres://`) happens to match the image name, and you do need to set ports if you want access *outside* the compose network (e.g. to connect psql on your local host). Also there's no need for strikethrough; if people want to see how it developed they can look at the history, the next reader should only see the correct information.

Comment: So far I have "corrected" the  answer 15 times. Which is the exact point I am trying to make. The documentation is bad because it requires prior knowledge of Docker or in this case `postgres` protocol. I have made the answer a community wiki, so eventually people with prior experience (as oppose to reading the docs) can correct the mistakes.

As I wrote "If any of the following is wrong - blame the horrible documentation."

Comment: But thx @jonrsharpe - I will change the answer to reflect... what-you-said.

Comment: TODO: add info about using `--exit-code-from tests` to tear down containers after tests has executed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49485880/205696

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter You do realize that your part "Fix: 2. copy everything from my current directory into the nodejs 14 image." is misleading, right? Using volumes does not copy files but you have different options for using them...
I know you love docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
In my humble opinion, Docker is not that badly documented but it is an heavy piece to eat and I can understand your frustration. It requires a lot of (too much?) efforts.

Comment: Thanks @ncenerar. I didn't know that. I thought that directories got symlinked. I will update part 2. My main issue with the docker documentation is that it doesn't explain what is Docker and what is part of a technology that is containerized. You have to have prior knowledge of a lot of disparent technologies before you can understand the documentation proper. "volumes are often a better choice than persisting data in a container’s writable layer" and "increase the container’s performance by avoiding writing into the container’s writable layer." seems conflicting. Both describe `volume`?

Comment: ive spend at least a week trying to replicate in docker what I can setup in 20 minutes without it. Im glad im not the only one who finds the documentation aweful. Should jsut be a list of what keywords can be used in the compose file and what each of them do.